# Modal blocks underlying views buttons when closed

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a NavigationView with the following code:

```
struct PeopleListView: View {    
    var body: some View {


    NavigationView{
    // ...
    }
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
    .sheet(isPresented: $showAddPersonModal) {
         AddPersonView()
    }
   //...
}
```

The addButton and settingsButton are described the following:

```
@State var showAddPersonModal = false

var addButton: some View {
    Button(action: {
        showAddPersonModal.toggle()
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    })
}
```

The AddPersonView is defined the following way:

```
struct AddPersonView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    // ...
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        // ...
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton)
    }
}

var closeButton: some View {
    Button("Close") {
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

My problem:

Dismissing the modal view AddPersonView dismisses the view, but afterwards it is not possible to tab the + Button in the main View any more until the view gets refreshed by restarting the app or opening another view with NavigationLink.

Comment: Do you navigate to the `AddPersonView` from `PeopleListView`? If so, you shouldn't need another `NavigationView`

Comment: I open the AddPersonView in a sheet, not via NavigationLink. So I think I need the second NavigationView to enable NavBarItems. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Nevermind I think you're fine. Can you try passing a binding of `showAddPerson` into `AddPersonView` and have the `closeButton` perform the action of `showAddPerson = false`?

Comment: I tried it but this does not change the problem.

Comment: Can you try `self.dismiss.wrappedValue.dismiss()`?

Comment: Value of type 'DismissAction' has no member 'dismiss'

Comment: Replace `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` with `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` and then try my previous suggestion but with `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

Comment: The problem still exists. I also get the problem when I close the modal by dragging the View down as it is possible in the new iOS.

Comment: Have you already tried adding `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` or using `.onTapGesture()` for your button? Also, try tapping around the plus button if that triggers anything too. I thought the issue could be related that the app tricked itself into thinking the sheet was still opened, but I'm not quite sure what's going on because I have an almost identical functionality in my app that works just fine (minus the `NavigationView` in the sheet) and I'm not able to replicate this code on my machine.

Comment: Both don't fix it 